# Multidimensional numerical Fourier transform

Tags: numerical-integration, distributions, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to numerically compute the Fourier transform of the following bump function:

$$\hat{r}(k)=\int r(x)e^{ikx}dx$$,

where $r\in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$, namely:

$$r(x)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right),&\|x\|<1,\\0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

Thus $$\hat{r}(k)=\int\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right)\exp(ikx)dx,\qquad\|x\|<1$$
and $0$ otherwise.

Or $$\hat{r}(k)=\int\int\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{4}-y^{4}}\right)\exp(ik(x^2+y^2))dxdy,\qquad\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<1$$
and $0$ otherwise.

Now, the first thing I notice is that my 3D Plot is discontinuous:

```
Plot3D[Piecewise[{{Exp[-(1 - x^4 - y^4)^(-1)], 
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}, {0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] >= 1}}], {x, -1, 
1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 0.5}]
```

And using NIntegrate doesn't yield anything either when I use

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = Circle[]
Assuming[Element[k, \[ScriptCapitalR]], {NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{Exp[-(1/(1 - 
x^4 - y^4))]*Exp[I*k*(x^2 + y^2)], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}, {0, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] 
>= 1}}], {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]}]
```

Comment: Using ``Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]; PrintDefinitions[NFourierTransform]`` you can see the source code for this particular function, and as you can see there is no definition for multidimensional Fourier transforms, so this is a no go. On the upside you can see that, just as it says in the documentation, this function directly uses `NIntegrate` so you will lose nothing by using `NIntegrate` directly, you don't need `NFourierTransform`.

Comment: @C.E. See the edit.

Comment: 1. “Do I also have to set some parameters on $k$?” Of course, you're doing a numeric transform. 2. What do you mean by $r\in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$? The $x$ in $r(x)$ is a complex number?

Comment: @xzczd $C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is the space of smooth functions with compact support over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, which should also answer your second question: $x$ is a real number. Mind you, the function space shouldn't really be too important since I've already provided an explicit example of such a function, namely $r(x)$.

Comment: Well, I'm not that good at math, but doesn't $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ represent **2** dimensional? Also, if $x$ is just a real number, how can $\exp\left(-\frac{1}{1-x^{2}}\right)$ be translated to `Exp[-(1/(1 - x^2)) - 1/(1 - y^2)]`?

Comment: @xzczd See the edits

Comment: Then as said above, $k$ should be a number because you're doing numeric transform. For example: `With[{k = 1}, 
 NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{Exp[-(1/(1 - x^4 - y^4))]*Exp[I*k*(x^2 + y^2)], 
     Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}}], {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}]]`

Comment: @xzczd Right, but that doesn't allow me to **plot** the Fourier transform or spectrum.

Comment: Just use e.g. `Table[NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{Exp[-(1/(1 - x^4 - y^4))]*Exp[I*k*(x^2 + y^2)], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}}], {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}],{k,-10,10}]//Abs//ListLinePlot`, if you want to use `Plot`, then `func[k_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[Piecewise[{{Exp[-(1/(1 - x^4 - y^4))]*Exp[I*k*(x^2 + y^2)], Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1}}], {y, -1, 1}, {x, -1, 1}];Plot[func[k]//Abs,{k,-10,10}](*Probably slow*)`.